Identify a movie about Libyan leader
Long ago, I saw a film about war. It’s a historical war drama about the resistance of a Libyan leader, Omar Mukhtar, against Italian colonization in the early 20th century. The film portrays his leadership and struggle for independence. Does anyone know the name of this movie?
I really don't remember the whole story, but could anyone assist, please?
Further details:
Year: I think I watched it 7-10 years ago, but it was on TV.
Language: English.

Hi. Do you remember the year? The country\language?

Not even the approximate decade? Or when you watched it? (2 years ago? 10? 20?)

Damn, I was all ready to score with "Groundhog Day" as my answer.

Surely there's a mix up (during restoring?) here. The question and answer don't match at all.

Sounds like the romantic fantasy movie If Only (2004) with Jennifer Love Hewitt.

After his impetuous musician girlfriend, Samantha, dies in an accident shortly after they had a fight (and nearly broke up), a grief-stricken British businessman, Ian Wyndham, living in London gets a chance to relive the day all over again, in the hope of changing the events that led up to her getting killed.

All the elements you mentioned (his broken watch, the old country house, her singing in a theater etc.) are there and some of them appear in the trailer:



